# How to filter based on the user entry from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I have an array of objects

```
let array = [{name: "singpore"}, {name: "French Polynesia"}, {name: "poland"}, {name: "portugal"}]
```

I am trying to implement with below logic

```
 array.filter((item) => {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
  });
```

I am trying to search based on "po", when i search with po i am able to get all the records in the same order.

But i need to get the results in the below order to match the first characters

Current output:

```
[{name: "singpore"}, {name: "French Polynesia"}, {name: "poland"}, {name: "portugal"}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{name: "poland"}, {name: "portugal"}, {name: "singpore"}, {name: "French Polynesia"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `sort()` after filtering

```js
let array = [
  { name: "singpore" },
  { name: "French Polynesia" },
  { name: "poland" },
  { name: "portugal" }
];

let searchText = "po";

let filteredArray = array
  .filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))
  //compare the index of the search text in each name
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) - b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` then sort the values using the indexes!

```js
let array = [{
  name: "singpore"
}, {
  name: "French Polynesia"
}, {
  name: "poland"
}, {
  name: "portugal"
}]
const searchText = 'po';
console.log(array.filter((item) => {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
}).sort((a, b) => {
  const indexA= a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText);
  const indexB= b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText);
  return indexA - indexB;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by below method

```
const array = [
  { name: "singpore" },
  { name: "French Polynesia" },
  { name: "poland" },
  { name: "portugal" }
];

const searchText = "po";

const filteredArray = array.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))

const sortedArray = filteredArray.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) - b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText));

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you aim to organize your items using a function `repr` that represents each item by the index of the initial occurrence of the term 'po' within the item's name. The `TrueSet` is specifically tailored for this purpose (see the[@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library)

```
import {TrueSet} from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import {ORDER} from "@ut8pia/classifier/global.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [{name: "singpore"}, {name: "French Polynesia"}, {name: "poland"}, {name: "portugal"}],
    expected = [{name: "poland"}, {name: "portugal"}, {name: "singpore"}, {name: "French Polynesia"}];
```

All you need to do is add your data to the `TrueSet`. However, I would like to further suggest that utilizing a `Regular Expression` as the `query` could significantly enhance the proposed solution, making it both simpler and more powerful.

```
const 
    query = /po/i,
    repr = item => item.name.match(query).index,
    got = TrueSet.of(repr, ORDER.ASCENDING)
        .letAll(data.filter(item => item.name.match(query)));
```

You can test the proposed solution by:

```
assert.deepEqual(got.toArray(), expected)
```